# ValidateRequest in Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following `header` of `ASP.Net MVC` page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NEOGOV_Ideas.Models.SubIdeaAdminPage>"
ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

I need to move this page to Razor syntax. How should I set ValidateRequest?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't need that line in the view, instead use the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute on the controller method.

Make sure you've got this in your web.config if you're using ASP .net 4.0 (which I presume you are if you're using MVC 3)

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Martin

Comment: FYI - MVC 3 doesn't require the <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> flag any more.  It's generally recommended that you not put that in config if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 27):

Decorate your action method with `ValidateInput` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult index()
{
    return view();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From MVC 4 we can allow html content only for property of model class, not for the whole request. Just need to mark property by attribute AllowHtml

```
public class EditorialPixlocateRequestViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Xml { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Razor syntax in a CSHTML page without MVC, this was the solution that ultimately worked for me.  The link below lead me to this result.

```
var xml = Request.Unvalidated().Form["Xml"];
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5317736/How-to-avoid-potential-dangerous-request-From-valu